# SU binaries stop working randomly and require device reboot

Tags: rooting, supersu

I'm having this very strange problem with rooted devices: SU binaries are installed along with SuperSU and everything works fine. From time to time SU stops working until I reboot the device. If I open SuperSU I get the message saying I should install the binaries. Testing from shell SU doesn't work either.

I am not able to reproduce this reliably but I have noticed it right after reboot. So I turn the device on, SU doesn't work, then I reboot and then it does.

The device is running Lollipop and SuperSu version is 2.65. This matches the SU binaries version, I checked. Hardware is a prototype device based on a phone, not sure about the details though. I do know it has a Mediatek processor.

Comment: is it a rooted "Production" build? or another "User-debug"/"Engineer" build?

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui I'm not sure what the difference is but I would guess it's a production build. We received the android build from the hardware manufacturer and someone rooted it for us. I'm contacting them as well.

Comment: Check my profile for my email address, and contact me, because this discussion should not be public.